# String to time format in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

here is my code,

```
NSString *starttime =@"05:00:00";
```

it is in string format ,i want that in `HH:MM:SS`
,please say how to do,
this is what i did, but it shows  `1999-12-31 23:30:33`

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
              [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];

 NSDate *startTime = [dateFormat dateFromString:starttime];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a time zone like so:

```
NSString *starttime =@"5:00:00";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];
[dateFormat setTimeZone: [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
NSDate *startTime = [dateFormat dateFromString:starttime];
```

which will convert to : 2000-01-01 05:00:00 UTC

Comment: please ,tell me how can i call the array from one method to another method in the same class in objective c?please help me to do .

Comment: this sounds like an unrelated problem. If this is a different problem post it separately.